# WebServlet url-pattern ending by /jsfinspector

Tags: servlets

I'd like to map a servlet for every url ending with "/jsfinspector". For example:

- `http://localhost/myapp/pages/somewhere/jsfinspector`
- `http://localhost/myapp/jsfinspector`

Is it possible to do that? In a very simple way, without declaring all possible url patterns in web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Servlet API doesn't support that.

Your best bet is creating a `@WebFilter("/*")` which forwards to `@WebServlet("/jsfinspector")` when the URL matches, as shown below:

```
if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/jsfinspector")) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsfinspector").forward(request, response);
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

You can if necessary extract the original request URI in servlet as below:

```
String originalRequestURI = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispachter.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC! It helps a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could think about creating a filter to intercept every request and eventually redirect the flow. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html